# Exclude portion of string when using where clause

Tags: c#, linq, observablecollection

I am using the following to populate a list of filtered items to a DataGridView in a windows forms application I am working on. The current problem I am running into is that the items populated to the datagridview end in .zip

```
ObservableCollection<LogNames> filteredLogs = new ObservableCollection<LogNames>(selectedLogs.Where(f => f.Name.Contains(FilterTBox.Text)));
```

If I try and filter using 'ip' it pulls all the values. Is there a way to have the where clause not evaluate the extension portion or anything ending in a .zip

Comment: Can't you just do a string replace to remove the extension?

Comment: I could but I need the portion as the application will be used to copy selected files to a backup location

Comment: Take a look at [`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Well you don't need to replace it for good, just for the comparison

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure this `where clause not evaluate`? you want to avoid this after or before `Where`

you can try like this

```
selectedLogs.Select( o => o.ToString().Replace(..)).ToList().
Where(f => f.Name.Contains(FilterTBox.Text))
```